# What AST tool to use to generate builder DSL

Tags: java, groovy, delegates, abstract-syntax-tree, builder

I am aware that Groovy provides AST annotations to generate builders on the fly, but they do not fit what I want to do exactly.
I created a nice builder DSL that allows to express builds with strong typing involved (leveraging full IDE support during construction). This helps on writing them, as well as refactoring them.

This looks like:

```
     Modem modem = ModemBuilder.modem {
        macAddress = new MacAddress("11:22:33:44:55:66")
        it.returnTechnology = ReturnTechnology.TPM // using it limits scope to current block, easy to discover properties!
        monitorType = MonitoringType.ADVANCED
        forwardId = Id.fromSystemId(17)
        lineUpSettings(outputPowerDbm: 2.dB, bandwidthHz: 10.mhz) // using named params 
        s2Settings {
            transportMode = TransportMode.S2
            centerFrequency = 14.05.ghz
            s2ChannelSettings(name: "mys2") { // using params and closure
                acmEnabled = true
                nominalMod = ModCod._DPSK_6_4
            }
        }
     }
```

The key component is DelegateBuilder

```
abstract class DelegateBuilder<T> {
   public T build(Closure body)
   {
      return build(body, this)
   }

   public T build(Closure body, DelegateBuilder target, def owner = null)
   {
       if (!owner) owner = body.owner
       def code = body.rehydrate(target, owner, this)
       code.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
       code(target)
       return target.target as T
   }

   static public <E> E addNamedArguments(Map arguments, E target) {
       arguments.each { k, v -> target."$k" = v }
       return target as E
   }

   abstract T getTarget()

}
```

and you can then create per object a builder following using a @Delegate for automatic property resolving, and @DelegatesTo for nesting.

Example for above:

```
class ModemBuilder extends DelegateBuilder<Modem> {

    @Delegate
    Modem target = new Modem()

    static Modem modem(@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class, options = "my.company.ModemBuilder")
                   @DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = ModemBuilder) Closure body)
    {
        return new ModemBuilder().build(body)
    }

    static Modem modem(Map params,
                   @ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class, options = "my.company.ModemBuilder")
                   @DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = ModemBuilder) Closure body = {})
    {
        return addNamedArguments(params, modem(body))
    }

    LineUpSettings lineUpSettings(@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class, options = "my.company.LineUpSettingsBuilder")
                              @DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = LineUpSettingsBuilder) Closure body)
    {
        target.lineUpSettings = LineUpSettingsBuilder.lineUpSettings(body)
    }

    LineUpSettings lineUpSettings(Map params,
                              @ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class, options = "ntc.nms.ts.build.builders.modem.LineUpSettingsBuilder")
                              @DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = LineUpSettingsBuilder) Closure body = {})
    {
        target.lineUpSettings = addNamedArguments(params, LineUpSettingsBuilder.lineUpSettings(body))
    }


    S2Settings s2Settings(@ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class, options = "ntc.nms.ts.build.builders.modem.S2SettingsBuilder")
                      @DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = S2SettingsBuilder) Closure body)
    {
        target.s2Settings = S2SettingsBuilder.s2Settings(body)
    }

    S2Settings s2Settings(Map params,
                      @ClosureParams(value = SimpleType.class, options = "my.company.S2SettingsBuilder")
                      @DelegatesTo(strategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST, value = S2SettingsBuilder) Closure body = {})
    {
        target.s2Settings = addNamedArguments(params, S2SettingsBuilder.s2Settings(body))
    }
```

So one creates a Builder class for every corresponding type, and two static shortcut methods to get started. One also refers every nested object so that it can be built in one structure.
This is always the same code, and lends itself to be generated nstead of written as there is no logic involved other than:

- create two static methods using camelcased name of your type
- for every type that reside in company package, create a method that accepts the builder code

As everything is convention (Builder name is xxxBuilder) this should be do-able by AST. I would think one could cut this to:

```
@ClosureBuilder(Modem)
class ModemBuilder {}
```

As this says clearly where to store the builder, and what to scan/build.

How could I best approach this via Groovy AST? What tools to use? The AST documentation proposes several ways, and I know there are people developing tools.

Comment: How about `groovyConsole`?

Comment: yes, I have experimented with that to inspect the AST tree. It looks great. But I still need a good way to generate that AST and there are at least three ways of doing so via standard Groovy, and then some third-party DSL's too. I also wonder whteher to use global or local, and what phase etc. This is tricky stuff, would like to be in the right direction